# How to take directory path as input from the user

Tags: perl

I want to take a directory path as input from the user in Perl. What is the method to do that?

I tried the below code, but it didn't work:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $abc = "perl";

print "Enter the directory path\n";
my $path = <STDIN>;

mkdir($path/$abc);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few errors.

You need to `chomp` the input to remove the trailing newline character.

You need to add quotes around the path; otherwise Perl treats `/` as division.  You likely saw a warning message for that.

You can't use [mkdir](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/mkdir.html) to create a directory structure.  The docs tell you to use `mkpath` from `File::Path`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Path qw(mkpath);

my $abc = "perl";

print "Enter the directory path\n";
my $path = <STDIN>;
chomp $path;

mkpath("$path/$abc");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the link to understand what permissions are required to create a directory - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/331895/required-permission-to-create-directory

Below is an example code that I might use if I have to create a directory structure (the solution is open for feedback):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $abc = "perl";
print "Enter the directory path\n";
my $path = <STDIN>;

# chomp: remove newline from the end of input
chomp $path;

# final directory path
my $dir = "$path/$abc";

# exit if input directory does not exist
unless (-d $path) {
        print "$path does not exist, try again\n";
        exit 1;
}

# exit if there is no write permission 
# write permission is required to create new directory
unless (-w $path) {
        print "$path is not writable, try another path\n";
        exit 1;
}

# so far, so good, try creating directory
if (mkdir($dir)) {
        print "$dir created";
        exit 0;
} else {
        # if the directory already exist you will get
        #       Cannot create /opt/perl/perl: File exists
        # if there is no execute permission on input directory
        #       Cannot create /opt/perl/perl: Permission denied
        die "Cannot create $dir: $!\n";
}
```

Comment: File::Path's make_path will avoid that work for you :)